# Convergence almost surely question

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, convergence-divergence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Suppose you have a sequence of independent random variables {$X_i, i\geq1$}, such that
$$\Bbb P(X_i=i^2 -1)=i^{-2},$$ $$ \Bbb P(X_i=-1)=1-i^{-2}.$$
Then, $\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ converges almost surely to a constant c. Find the value of c.

For this question, I thought of applying the strong law of large numbers which says:
$$ \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$ converges almost surely to $\mu$, where {$X_i, i\geq1$} is a sequence of IID random variables whose mean $\mu$ exists.

However, for the question above, $\mu=0$. But c is not equal to $0$. c is, in fact, equal to -1.

Any clarification on this would greatly be appreciated, as I'm not sure how $c=-1$.

Comment: It may help to know that the sum of the reciprocals of the squares is finite, so that the expected number of "large values" in the infinite sum is finite also.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Borel-Cantelli lemma.  Since $\sum_{n \geq 1} \mathbb{P}(X_n \neq -1) = \sum_{n \geq 1} n^{-2} < \infty$, we know that almost surely, $X_n = -1$ for all $n$ sufficiently large.   Then the desired result follows easily: if $(a_n)$ is a sequence that is eventually constant, it's straightforward to verify that $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n$ converges to that constant as $N \to \infty$.